# Amazon S3 region transfer?

Tags: amazon-s3, transfer, region

How I can transfer the content of a S3 bucket of a specific region to another S3 bucket of another specific region?
Please provide the simplest way and detailed steps if you can.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this with the [AWS Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home) or one of the commercial tools such as Bucket Explorer.

You need to select the files you want to transfer, then `copy/cut` and `paste` them into the new bucket. This works for buckets in the same region or different regions.

Comment: Just remember you will pay for the transfer between buckets just as you would for uploading them.

Comment: But if I have thousands of files they cannot be selected in AWS Console!

Comment: @AndreyRegentov - No, in that case use BucketExplorer or Cloudberry explorer. Or do it programatically using the S3 API or SDKs.