# S3 copy_object between regions in ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

How to coppy files between buckets in diffrent regions in AWS S3 using ruby aws-sdk-s3 gem?
Buckets are in regions: '**eu-central-1**' (target_bucket) and '**eu-west-1**' (source_bucket).
I want to make copy of **s3://source_bucket/name_base.checksum** to **s3://target_bucket/source_bucket/name_base.checksum**

Error:

```
[ERROR] The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

Testing ruby code:

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'

source_bucket = 'source_bucket'
target_bucket = 'target_bucket'
name_base = 'funny_name'

begin
  s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
    access_key_id: '***',
    secret_access_key: '***',
    region: 'eu-west-1' # I tested also 'eu-central-1'
  )

  s3.copy_object({
    bucket: "#{target_bucket}",
    copy_source: "#{source_bucket}/#{name_base}.checksum",
    key: "#{source_bucket}/#{name_base}.checksum"
  })
rescue Aws::S3::Errors::ServiceError => e
  puts "[ERROR] #{e.message}"
end
```

I can't find any usefull information about this use case in documentation:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingRuby.html
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#copy_object-instance_method

I found old thread from 2011 I hope something changed in this case: 
  [Amazon S3 region transfer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602992/amazon-s3-region-transfer)

Any news?